# already opened files in a directory can still be saved after the directory is deleted - Linux

Tags: linux

This is annoying feature of Linux.

If I opened a file in a directory and then delete the directory, and copy another directory having the same name to the same place, I can still edit and save the opened file, but it goes to trash!
I have made the same mistakes for several times. I carries on editing the opened file and thought it would be saved to the newly copied directory, but it didn't and finally I lost all the editing.

Can I possibly disable this feature?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: This feature is not annoying, and many utilities require it. Linux and most Posix systems (in particular all Unix-like systems) require that behavior. And I don't understand exactly what you mean by deleting a directory. The `rmdir(2)` syscall would fail if you still have some file entry in the directory. Your editor should detect your situation (`emacs` does that). You also should learn to use a version control system (like `git`) for your source code.

Comment: which editor you use to edit files? logically it should throw an error/warning if you save a file in non-existent(deleted) directory.

Comment: If it goes into the *Trash* you didn't delete the file, but moved it, and the file is edited at its new location. It's a feature.

Answer (score 2):

This is functioning as-designed. File descriptors can remain open even after a file is unlinked. The manual page for unlink(2) says:

> unlink()  deletes  a  name  from the file system...If  the  name  referred to a socket, fifo or device the name for it is removed but processes which have the object open may  continue to use it.